# How to add tomcat's lib in ant build's classpath?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, ant

- I needed servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar in my eclipse dynamic web
  project.

  - So I went to Project -> Properties -> Targeted Runtimes -> Checked Apache Tomcat 6.0.
  - Now I try to build a war file using Ant as I have to deploy the war file on a unix machine.
  - **Problem -** Ant build fails (package javax.servlet does not exist, etc etc) because the jar files are not under /WEB-INF/lib/. How do I include these jar files in the classpath ? I can't hardcode it as the path is different in windows(D:\Program Files\Apache...) and unix(/usr/local/apache..).
  - Current classpath-

> ```
> <path id="compile.classpath">
>     <fileset dir="${web.home}/WEB-INF/lib">
>         <include name="*.jar"/>
>     </fileset>
> </path>
> ```

p.s. **My Apache-Tomcat versions are different on windows(6.0.32) and unix(6.0.36)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check if a variable like `CATALINA_HOME` is set on any machine where the build might run, then you could use something like:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${web.home}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${env.CATALINA_HOME}/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: would this work if my apache-tomcat versions are different on windows and unix ? Should I manually copy the .jar files from unix box and place them in my windows' env.CATALINA_HOME dir ?

Comment: No, you should not manually copy anything.  If the environment variable is set on both machines (one machine it is set to `C:\Foo\Bar\apache-tomcat-6.0.32` and on the other to `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.27`) then then it should put Tomcat's `/lib` .jars on your classpath in either situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Double click on your `build.xml` -> Run as -> Ant build...
2. Choose "Classpath" and add the jars needed

I think that should be enough

Comment: My tomcat versions are different on windows and unix. Wont adding jars the way you mentioned lead to errors like - java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:22)